# How to change position of label of y-axes in chartjs?

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I have a working code like in this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-darkness-x31u7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/index.js

I want ask, is there a possibility we could change the position of yaxes label to the top? (see the expected picture below).

I had actually tried the below code but it displays in the middle of gridline instead of top.

```
scales: {
    yAxes: [
      {
        ticks: {
          mirror: true,
        },
      },
    ],
}
```

---

**Current Output:**

[image]

**Expected Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mirror is actually fine to move the yaxes labels to inside. Your only problem is to move the labels upward so that it won't intersect with the x-gridlines. And for that, you can use **labelOffset** property to achieve it, and then you can also put some **padding** to move the label a little a bit from the y-line.

> labelOffset - Distance in pixels to offset the label from the centre point of the tick (in the x direction for the x axis, and the y direction for the y axis).

So in all, your code would look like this below:

```
yAxes: [
    {
        ticks: {
            mirror: true,
            padding: -10,
            labelOffset: -10
        }
    }
]
```

[see more props and their definition here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/)

Answer (score 0):

Dont think that this is possible, the closes you can get to this as far as I know is this.

Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chartjs-2-forked-rgiyf?file=/src/index.js
[image]

code:

```
scales: {
    yAxes: [
      {
        ticks: {
          padding: -30
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

There is a workaround for this, if you put a `null` value as the first entry in your dataset and an empty string in the labels array you will get this:
[image]